# VS Code started displaying Python version in terminal after every command, and I'm not sure why

Tags: visual-studio-code

I couldn't find which setting enables or disables this - I'm working on a Python project, and the integrated terminal in VS Code started displaying the Python version in parentheses after every command. Example:

```
In a world of ones and zeros, are you a zero, or The Chosen One? ~/My Corner/Games/Shapez/Code
> echo "Test"
Test
(3.10.0)
```

It still does this when I close and reopen VS  Code. My regular terminal outside of VS Code does not do this. What setting do I have to change to disable this?